# How to create a CSS transition where the image scales out of the thumbnail?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to create a transition like the one at http://google.com/photos. Click on Go To Google Photos. If you click on a photo, you will see that the photo transitions from it current container (the thumbnail) to the center and the back of the screen is blacked out. When we close the preview, the photo transitions back to the thumbnail container. How do you implement such a transition using CSS and Jquery? I tried doing so in CSS but I'm only only able to get the photo to transition from the center of the page to show the user its full screen not from where the thumbnail of the photo is located.

Here's what I have so far:

```
@keyframes fadeInScale {
    0%{
        opacity:0;
        transform: scale(0.5);
    }
    100%{
        opacity:1;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

@keyframes fadeOutScale {
    0%{
        opacity:1;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    100%{
        opacity:0;
        transform: scale(0.5);
    }
}

.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    height: 0;
    z-index: 500;
    overflow: auto;
    transition: all 0.4s;

    &.show {
        top: 0px;
        height: 100%;
    }
}


.fade-scale-in {
    display: block;
    animation: fadeInScale 0.3s 1 ease-out;
}

.fade-scale-out {
    display: block;
    animation: fadeOutScale 0.3s 1 ease-out;
}
```

Here's the html

When I click on the div with the image, I add the class `fade-scale-in` to the overlay that shows the image in full screen. The image gets shown in a full screen preview overlay. When you exit the preview overlay, I add the class `fade-scale-out` and remove the class `fade-scale-in` to the overlay that shows the image in full screen.